# Render User Control and Fire Control Events

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls

I'm trying to load a user control in code and store the output as a string variable. At the moment I've got the below code:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

WidgetControlBase widget = (WidgetControlBase)LoadControl("/controls/mycontrol.ascx");
widget.RenderControl(htw);
```

The problem is that the `RenderControl` method doesn't fire any of the control events so anything I add in the control `Page_Load` doesn't happen.

I've tried loading the control in a `PlaceHolder` and then rendering the `PlaceHolder` like so:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

WidgetControlBase widget = (WidgetControlBase)LoadControl("/controls/mycontrol.ascx");

myPlaceholder.Controls.Add(widget);
myPlaceholder.RenderControl(htw);
```

However this seems to do the same as just using `RenderControl` direct on the control, it doesn't fire any events either.

Is there a way I can get a string containing the contents of my control while still firing the control events?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to render the control at the wrong point in the pages life cycle. Try moving the code from Page_Load to PreInit like so:

```
    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)

 {
            //custom code            

           base.OnPreInit(e);
 }
```

Detailed information about the page life cycle can be found here:
http://www.codeasp.net/articles/asp.net/20/aspnet-page-lifecycle

Comment: No luck, didn't make any difference. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure. You could try looking here:
http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx